# Proof of $\mathbb E[u(B_{t+s})\mid \mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[u(B_t)\mid B_s]$.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, brownian-motion

I reading the proof of R. Schilling in his book : Brownian motion, introduction to stochastic process, and his proof is really unclear for me. I want to prove that if $u$ is bounded, then $$\mathbb E[u(B_{t+s})\mid \mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[u(B_t)\mid B_s],$$
where $(\mathcal F_t)$ is an admissible filtration to $(B_t)$ (i.e. $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ for all $0\leq s\leq t$, and $(B_t)$ is a Brownian motion.

The proof goes as follow :

$$\mathbb E[u(B_{t+s})\mid \mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[u(B_{t+s}-B_s+B_s)\mid \mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[u(B_t+x)]|_{x=B_s}=\mathbb E[u(B_t)\mid B_s],$$
but I neither understand the notation $\mathbb E[u(B_t+x)]|_{x=B_s}$ nor the two last inequalities. I thought that $$\mathbb E[u(B_t+x)]|_{x=B_s}:=\mathbb E[u(B_t+B_s)\mid B_s=x],$$
but it doesn't really make sense. Any help is welcome.

Comment: $$\mathbb{E}[u(B_t+x)] \bigg|_{x=B_s}$$ is a short-hand for the function $$f(x) := \mathbb{E}[u(B_t+x)]$$ evaluted at $x=B_s$, i.e. $$\mathbb{E}[u(B_t+x)] \bigg|_{x=B_s} = f(B_s).$$

Comment: @saz: So, it's exactly $\mathbb E[u(B_t+B_s)]$, no ? So why doe he use this notation ?

Comment: No, it's not the same as the expression in your comment. This is already indicated by the fact that $f(B_s)$ is a random variable whereas $\mathbb{E}u(B_t+B_s)$ is just a constant.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just to look through my notation, could it be something as $\mathbb E[u(B_t+B_s)\mid B_s]$ ? This is a more comon notation, no ? @saz

Comment: Forget for the moment about conditional expectations. If $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables, then $$\mathbb{E}[u(x,Y)] \bigg|_{x=X}$$ is defined as $$\mathbb{E}[u(x,Y)] \bigg|_{x=X} := f(X)$$ where $$f(x) := \mathbb{E}(u(x,Y)).$$ There are no conditional expectations around. Note that, in general, $$\mathbb{E}[u(x,Y)] \bigg|_{x=X}  \neq \mathbb{E}(u(X,Y))$$ and $$\mathbb{E}[u(x,Y)] \bigg|_{x=X}  \neq \mathbb{E}(u(X,Y) \mid X).$$

Comment: @saz : in the book that you recommended me few timew ago (rené schilling, brownian motion). If you go page 334, lemma A3, formula (A.4), it's written $\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid X]=\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$ (and there is no proof of this fact, so I guess it is a definition)... So, is your last formula wrong, or is there a context that I didn't understand (I imagine that it's the second fact... but maybe you can explain what they want to say).

Comment: @saz : What do you think about my previous comment ?

Comment: They assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I'm assuming no such thing in my previous comment. The last formula in my previous comment fails, in general, to hold but if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then it's true.